# Does Death Knell give the bonus if the target fail the save but doesn't get killed?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

Inspired by [death knell vs regeneration](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/105148/death-knell-vs-regeneration).

I am assuming that [death knell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/death-knell) doesn't kill a creature with regeneration. If it is not the case then this question is pointless.

So let's assume I cast death knell on a troll with -50 hp. The troll fails its saving throw. Do I get the bonus normally granted?

Comment: Are we assuming the spell can stack with itself?

Comment: I though this spell allowed it explicitely, but apparently it doesn't. Maybe an errata? Anyway that's not the important part of the question so I remove it.

Comment: All spells are explicitly never allowed to stack with themselves, not even from different casters.

Answer (score 1):

Regeneration actively says (emphasis mine):

> Creatures with regeneration heal damage at a fixed rate, as with fast healing, but **they cannot die** as long as their regeneration is still functioning (although creatures with regeneration still fall unconscious when their hit points are below 0).

"They can not die" is the catch here. It is basically an implied Immunity, but it is not really one. What would immunity (not the damage type) do?

> Immunities **can also apply to** afflictions, conditions, spells (based on school, level, or save type), and **other effects** [e.g. death effects]. A creature that is immune *does not suffer from these effects, or any secondary effects that are triggered due to an immune effect.*

Let's keep in mind, it is **not** an immunity, but pretty close. You just **can not die** while having regeneration. Now, our problem still can't be solved with that alone. So, let's look at the spell:

Death Knell asks for a saving row. This can go through or fail. Now, let's disect what failing this saving throw means:

> [...] [the touched target] dies, **and** you gain 1d8 temporary hit points **and** a +2 enhancement bonus to Strength. **Additionally**, your effective caster level goes up by +1, improving spell effects dependent on caster level.

A pretty long list, but it starts with two words: **It dies.** Well, it would if it could, but because of regeneration, it does not die. Now, how does that affect the rest of the effects?

Here logic operator semantics come in: the death and all the bonuses are conjoined with a series of AND. AND is always "all inclusive". An object that is "red and spherical" is always both, otherwise it would be "red or spherical". So if you get "a red and spherical object" you always get the whole package of both properties<sup>1</sup>. In fact, AND means you either get ALL the contents of the package or none of the packages at all<sup>2</sup>.

So, the Troll can't die due to regeneration (as long as it still functions), and thus, because the boni and the death are a bundle, you shouldn't get any of the contents.

tl;dr:

## NO, you just wasted a spell.

<sup>1 - Order does not matter in case an AND or similar conjunction (additionally) is used: all parts conjoined this way are all one package to execute in one step - if one is impossible, all parts are not done. This is Mathematical logic. "IF you have a green house, THEN paint it black AND add red dots" means you have to do both - if something bars you from adding red dots OR paining it black, you do neither. The order of execution does not matter.
However, if some sort of "first do a, next do b" would be used, it would become a step by step procedure, which would trigger down one by one, just ignoring invalid statements. "IF you have a green house paint it black; add red dots" is (in math terms) fundamentally different, you just execute one order after another, ignoring impossible ones.</sup>

<sup>2 - unless you somehow hide an inclusive OR in the sentence (and not an XOR, which is exclusive)</sup>