# What, beyond correct elemental or alignment damage, can kill a regenerating creature?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, magic, regeneration

In pathfinder, disintegrate states that:

> Any creature reduced to 0 or fewer hit points by this spell is entirely disintegrated, leaving behind only a trace of fine dust.

This indicates to me that that troll, Demon, Devil or whatever is GONE. I can see however, that not everyone seems to think so.

What about the Finger of Death spell? It seems to only deal HP damage, 10/CL on a failed save, however, the rules state:

> Spells with the death descriptor directly attack a creature’s life force to cause immediate death, or to draw on the power of a dead or dying creature. The death ward spell protects against death effects, and some creature types are immune to death effects.

Which seems to indicate that being reduced to 0 this way is certain death, but is there anything that confirms this, or am i reading this wrong?

Comment: True story: after a vicious fight with a troll (that we weren't really supposed to fight), we were left with the question of what do you do with a regenerating creature. We didn't know how you were supposed to kill them. It turns out poking them in the eyes repeatedly until they (aka the GM) tell you how to end their misery works just fine.  The process goes even faster when you all start discussing how the party is going to take turns poking the troll's eyes through the night.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### The rules are unclear

It has been confirmed that trolls may suffocate to death in Pathfinder, as shown in [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/105154/21153). But the rules are actually saying the opposite (as shown in that answer as well), the regeneration must be stopped or the creature **cannot die**.

> Regeneration (Ex) A creature with this ability is difficult to kill. Creatures with regeneration heal damage at a fixed rate, as with fast healing, but **they cannot die as long as their regeneration is still functioning** (although creatures with regeneration still fall unconscious when their hit points are below 0). Certain attack forms, typically fire and acid, cause a creature's regeneration to stop functioning on the round following the attack. During this round, the creature does not heal any damage and can die normally. The creature's descriptive text describes the types of damage that cause the regeneration to cease functioning.

There is an open [FAQ request](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2qc2s&page=1?Can-a-a-troll-be-killed-by-death-effects) at paizo messageboards asking for clarification on wether trolls can be killed by death effects or not.

Also, notice that Pathfinder's version of [Regeneration](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules/#Regeneration_Ex) is worded differently from what we had in 3.5 ([link](http://dndsrd.net/abilitiesAndConditions.html#regeneration)), which made no mention of "they cannot die" and handled things using nonlethal damage instead. While the [Disintegrate](http://dndsrd.net/spellsDtoE.html#disintegrate) spell text is mostly the same, including the part where the target becomes *dust*.

### But you can try to remove their regeneration

One thing is certain, you must stop their regeneration, either with the correct damage type, with something that prevents regeneration, or removing regeneration from the creature (by [polymorphing](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/baleful-polymorph/), or [transfering it](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/transfer-regeneration/)).

As much as it sounds ridiculous that a bunch of dust may still regenerate back to life, so is instantly killing them with a death effect and having them return to life a few rounds later.

There are many ways to *disable* them (sleep, burying, throwing underwater, locking their soul in a gem), but those won't kill the creature.

Comment: Would a *disintegrate* spell that reduces a troll's hp to 0 subsequently transform the troll into a "trace of fine dust" ***that's still alive?***

Comment: @HeyICanChan I dont think that's intended, but its whats *raw*. Even worse is when you target a troll with something that rips their soul off their body and they are **still alive**.

Comment: (It may be worth mentioning that while *Pathfinder* changed substantially from its *D&D 3.5* forebear the rules for the special ability [regeneration](http://dndsrd.net/abilitiesAndConditions.html#regeneration), *Pathfinder* let largely alone its forebear's description of the spell [*disintegrate*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsDtoE.html#disintegrate)! *Sigh.* Despite moving on to a second edition, *Pathfinder*'s tech never has quite caught up to its ambition.)

Comment: I suppose the various forms of "drained by undead" would also be inconclusive.

Comment: Stacking [negative levels](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/special-abilities#TOC-Energy-Drain-and-Negative-Levels) or even *ability drain* would be effective at disabling the creature, though.

Comment: It is awkward, but I would interpret it (if maintaining RAW) as something like the dust magically re-forming into the creature, and once HP is back to full it's like the disintegration never happened. Though in combat I would still have the disintegrated creature be out of commission until regeneration had advanced quite a bit.

Comment: I'm not sure how **they cannot die** is "unclear".  Can you clarify?

Comment: @Yakk see the linked answer, there is a flavor text from rise of runelords claiming that trolls were killed being suffocated. Its unclear because we dont know if its intended that creatures with regeneration cannot die while their regeneration is active.

Comment: This is one of the 'best worst' answers I've seen. Thanks ;)

I think, however, I am going to run it like this:

Disintegrate: It makes no sense to heal hit point damage from fine dust, Just like it wouldn't survive flesh to stone -> disintegrate. Thus, being turned into powder, is to be killed.
Spells with the Death descriptor drain life force, which could be spoken of as the force that binds the soul to the flesh. If it goes, you die, even with Regen. Else, how could a troll ever die from old age?

Anyhow, that's how I am going to run it, unless i hear very good arguments against it.

Comment: @ShadowKras I don't see the word "killed", just "drowning before they regenerated back to consciousness".  The first part of drowning sets your HP to a fixed value and makes you unconscious; regeneration only clears unconsciousness due to HP loss not unconsciousness due to drowning.  And KO'd trolls are not a threat (and are potentially carried far away from the battle, or unable to stop drowning without external help).

Comment: @Yakk if this was clear, the FAQ request wouldnt have over 100 votes.

Answer (score 3):

I did consider this once, and the best I could come up with was:
" Regeneration also does not restore hit points lost from starvation, thirst, or suffocation"
(https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Regeneration-Ex-)

So, burying something in a big pile of sand, or locking them up and waiting.
There are also a few spells that can accelerate hunger like Feast Of Ashes.

Comment: How does this actually kill the creature however?

Comment: Suffocation by itself (eventually) causes death regardless of hitpoints, and the starvation/thirst rules cause lethal damage after enough time has elapsed, which wouldn't be covered by Regeneration.

Comment: "they cannot die as long as their regeneration is still functioning" -- regeneration doesn't say "does not die because the lethal damage will be healed" or "does not die from hit point damage", it simply states "cannot die"

Comment: @Yakk: I think to make this answer work as a justification, we need to argue that regeneration needs food / air, i.e. biological "fuel", and thus depriving a creature of those things actually stops their regeneration from functioning.  Or maybe we can just interpret the wording as "stops it from functioning for damage from those sources", and thus the "as long as their regen is still functioning" doesn't help them.